# Eloquent Tinker - Undefined Constant

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I'm following along with this set of [tutorials](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8) on laravel (They're excellent), and I keep running into this error:

```
PHP error:  Use of undefined constant Article
```

whenever I enter this line of code:

```
$article = new App/Article;
```

I've followed everything to the letter, and used the command:

```
$ php artisan make:model Article
Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2015_04_11_152306_create_ar
```

What I find unusual is that in the tutorial, no migration was created when this command was called. Anyways, I'm trying to enter some data into my sqlite database through tinker, but I'm unable to create an Article object, and therefore cannot insert into the database. How would I got about either solving or bypassing this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use backslash `\`:

```
$article = new App\Article;
```

Comment: There should really be a faceplam tag that can be put on a question. Thanks for your help, http://www.gifsforum.com/images/gif/facepalm/grand/star-trek-picard-facepalm-eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3-1381.gif.